# Trying to press one button then play audios in sequence or random

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I am trying to press one button and the audio file plays one after another.

Here is my code below. I press play button and both sounds play at the same time.
I am trying to press play button and the sound starts and stop then the other sound file starts and stops. One button pressed for 2 sound files to press is my goal. Thank you

I am trying this in a loop but it is not working.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var sliderValue: UISlider!

    var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var player1:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    @IBAction func play(_ sender: AnyObject) {
           player.play()
           player1.play()
    }

    @IBAction func pause(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        player.pause()
    }
    @IBAction func stop(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        player.stop()
        player.currentTime = 0 
    }
    @IBAction func sliderChanged(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        player.volume = sliderValue.value 
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let audioPath =  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound1", ofType: "mp3")!
        let audioPath1 =  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound2", ofType: "mp3")!
        do {   
            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath))
            try player1 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath1))

        } catch{
            //Process Error here
        }      
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Play second sound after finish of one, You can user the delegate of AVAudioPlayer to know playing sound is completed or not.

Comment: i forgot to say. I am a newbie. Thanks rohit

Comment: visit this link https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVAudioPlayer for detail description about it

Comment: Great. I was looking for  this kind of documents. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can't do it in a loop!

The correct way to play a sound file after another is to use the `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`.

In your view controller, conform to `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    // ...
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer,
                         successfully flag: Bool) {

    }
}
```

As you can see, I added an `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying` method to the controller.

So you want to play `player` first, then `player1`, right?

In `viewDidLoad`, add this line:

```
player.delegate = self
```

And in the method I just added, write:

```
player1.play()
```

And the other IBAction methods should be changed a little:

```
@IBAction func play(_ sender: AnyObject) {
       player.play()
}

@IBAction func pause(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if player.isPlaying {
        player.pause()
    } else if player1.isPlaying {
        player1.pause()
    }

}
@IBAction func stop(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if player.isPlaying {
        player.stop()
    } else if player1.isPlaying {
        player1.stop()
    }
}
@IBAction func sliderChanged(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    player.volume = sliderValue.value 
    player1.volume = sliderValue.value
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. This is going to give me meat to chew on. I really appreciate this. yes, i do want to play player first then player1.

Comment: @MichaelContreras If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking that checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

If you can manage this also with another object `AVQueuePlayer`, you can find the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVQueuePlayer_Class/index.html) and [here](http://blog.brightinventions.pl/queueing-audio-files/) a guide.

Comment: If my answer is helpful please upvote it and mark as right if it is the approach you prefer, thank you :)

Comment: Oh, you must reach reputation 15. You can do it easy joining another stack exchange network.